# Yii2 - Subdomain to module routing

Tags: php, module, yii2, subdomain

I googled and searched here, but didnt find a solution... All that I found was subdomain to controller route... But thats not what I´m looking for...

So... here we go.

I have 2 subdomains:

```
sub-domain-a.site.com
sub-domain-b.site.com
```

And I have 2 modules:

```
module-a
module-b
```

I want Yii2 to redirect all requests to sub-domain-a to module-a and all requests to sub-domain-b to module-b...

so, if I have a controller  in module-a, I just call:

```
sub-domain-a.site.com/controller-a-1
```

instead of

```
www.site.com/module-a/controller-a-1
```

same thing with sub-domain-b and module-b...

How can I accomplish this with Yii??

Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

in config:

```
[
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'sub-domain-a.site.com/controller-a-1' => 'module-a/controller-a-1',
        ],
    ],
],
```

]

Comment: it doesnt work... actually, I do not want to put the controller in the rule... that way, I could use just one rule for any new controller that I create, without modifying any rules... what I have now in the rule array: 'http://sub-domain-a.site.com' => 'module-a' ... but it doesnt work